# How to set listgrid filter button properties?? - Smartgwt

Tags: java, smartgwt, listgrid

Using smartgwt (version:v9.0_2013-07-03/LGPL Development Only)
I need an example about how to set a custom button for the list grid's filter.
I just use new Button() but it appears far away from the grid not in the same place as the default filter button.

My code: ("this" refers to my listgrid)

```
this.setShowFilterEditor(showFilter);
this.setFilterOnKeypress(showFilter);
this.setFetchDelay(2000);
Button filterBtn = new Button();
filterBtn.setWidth(15);
filterBtn.setTitle("");
this.setFilterButtonProperties(filterBtn);
```

I didn't add any thing special to the button.

Comment: Can you post your code?

Comment: Have you tried anything ? If no try and get back with specific question, I yes then show your codes.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a bug. [I've postet a TestCase in the SmartClient-Forum.](http://forums.smartclient.com/showthread.php?p=113676) This is the only place where bug-reports can be entered.